# Laravel - How to get rows of permissions from another table set in roles table

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am very new to laravel and trying to get the all permission rows from the `permissions` table that set into the `roles` - `permission` field as a `json`

> Obviously, this is not working as aspected. It returns an array of
>   collections. However, I want each permission rows that associate with
>   the roles results in itself.

```
public function index()
{
    $roles = Role::all();

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $permissions[] = Permission::whereIn('id', json_decode($role->permission))->get();
    }

    dd($permissions);

}
```

### Permissions table

[image]

## Roles table

[image]

Comment: It is recommended to extract the permission assignment to a separate table. This would make it possible to implement constraint to ensure the referenced permission id does actually exists. An possible table name would be: `user_permission` with the following columns: `user_id` and `permission_id`

Comment: Do you mean by pivot table? Then how can I connect it with the roles?

Comment: Yes, using a pivot tables helps with correct data

Comment: So how about if I make tables like this `roles`, `permissions` `permission_role`, `role_user`?

Comment: Yes that would be good setup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to extract the permission field to a separate table. This would make it possible to implement constraints to ensure the referenced permission id and role id do actually exists. A possible table name would be: `permission_role` with the following columns: `permission_id` and `role_id`.

The migration could be setup like this:

```
Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('permission_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');

    $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
});
```

Comment: So how about if I make tables like this `roles`, `permissions` `permission_role`, `role_user`? With this would I be able to get all permissions for the role assigned to the user?

Comment: Let me try this approach. So I can use Many to Many or One to Many relationships. correct?

Comment: It depends, if different roles can have the same permissions use `Many to Many`, if permissions are at most used by one a `One to many` can be used @CodeLover